# LogUnsubEvent makes Subscriber unsubscribed but don't change Status on _Subscribers Data View

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, cloudpage, marketingcloudapi, subscriber

I execute this LogUnsubEvent on a CloudPage and it works well.

**The Subscriber get unsubscribed correctly but the value of Status don't change and remains Active on the table _Subscribers. Idk if i miss something or i have to include the value Status somewhere.**

This is my code, there's some extra info because the user arrives from a preferences cloudpage and i retrieve the info from there:

```
    %%[var @debug var @jid var @listid var @batchid var @email var @skey var @reason var @unsubscribeAll var @id_country var @domain var @upsert var @id_language

set @debug = 0 
set @jid = AttributeValue("jobid") 
set @listid = AttributeValue("listid") 
set @batchid = AttributeValue("_JobSubscriberBatchID") 
set @email = AttributeValue("emailaddr") 
set @skey = AttributeValue("_subscriberkey") 
set @reason = RequestParameter("reason")
set @id_country = RequestParameter("id_country") 
set @domain = RequestParameter("domain")
set @id_language = RequestParameter("id_language")

if RequestParameter("submitted2") == true THEN
set @upsert = UpsertData("user_email_preferences", 1, "id_user", @skey, "reason", @reason)



/* if we know the subscriber */ 

if not empty(@skey) then

var @lue var @lue_prop var @lue_statusCode var @overallStatus var @requestId var @Response var @Status var @Error

/* if unsubscribing from all, then set the job, batch and listids to blank, effectively doing a global unsub */ 

set @jid = "" 
set @listid = "" 
set @batchid = "" 


/* create a request to inject an unsub event into the LogUnsubEvent platform table */ 

set @lue = CreateObject("ExecuteRequest") 
SetObjectProperty(@lue,"Name","LogUnsubEvent")

/* In order to invoke the request, we need to associate the following information with it to define the subscriber context and the job context:

1. Subscriber Key
2. JobId associated with the email send
3. ListID the email was sent to
4. BatchID the email was sent to
5. Reason for the unsub    */ 

/* 1. define and associate Subscriber Key to the request */ 

set @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty") 
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "SubscriberKey") 
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @skey) 
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "Status") 
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", "Unsub") 
AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)

/* 2. define and associate JobID to the request */ 

if not empty(@jid) then 
set @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty") 
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "JobID") 
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @jid) 
AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop) 

endif

/* 3. define and associate ListID to the request */ 

if not empty(@listid) then 
set @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty") 
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "ListID") 
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @listid) 
AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop) 

endif

/* 4. define and associate BatchID to the request */ 
if not empty(@batchid) then 
set @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty") 
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "BatchID") 
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @batchid) 
AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop) 

endif

/* 5. define and associate unsub reason to the request */ 

set @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty") 
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "Reason") 
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @reason) 
AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)

/* finally, you invoke the request */ 

set @lue_statusCode = InvokeExecute(@lue, @overallStatus, @requestId)

/* extract messages from the response */ 

set @Response = Row(@lue_statusCode, 1) 
set @Status = Field(@Response,"StatusMessage") 
set @Error = Field(@Response,"ErrorCode")
endif

if @debug == 1 then 
output(concat(" jid: ", @jid)) 
output(concat(" listid: ", @listid)) 
output(concat(" batchid: ", @batchid)) 
output(concat(" email: ", @email)) 
output(concat(" skey: ", @skey)) 
output(concat(" reason: ", @reason)) 
output(concat(" unsubscribeAll: ", @unsubscribeAll)) 
output(concat(" overallStatus: ", @overallStatus)) 
output(concat(" requestId: ", @requestId)) 
output(concat(" Response: ", @Response)) 
output(concat(" Status: ", @Status)) 
output(concat(" Error: ", @Error)) 


endif
endif
]%%
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From the code you posted it seems that you were unsubscribing the subscribers from a specific publication list (hence the "ListID").
However, unsubscribing from a certain publication list does not mean the subscriber is unsubscribed at the subscriber level. So the data view "_Subscribers" will not reflect that correctly. Instead you can take a look at another data view called [ListSubscribers](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_listsubscribers.htm&type=5) where you can verify your unsub result.